# StoredProcedure performence improvements

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please check the Microsoft SQL StoredProcedure query bellow. With this query i am getting very slow to complete the process. For only 1000/2000 records taking over 20 sec of time to execute. Now my question is how can i tweak this query to improve its performance? I dont need whole working query but i need advice from expert that what can i do to improve its performance? Is there any better short way to write this same query? Please advice. Thanks in advance

Poor Performance SQL:

```
USE [Analytics]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER procedure [vision].[SancusoReferralExceptionsReport]
as
begin
 Declare @programid varchar(30) ;
 DECLARE @Startdate DATETIME = '1900-01-01'
 set @programid = '31';
     ;        
     with ProgramExceptions as
     (

            -- 1. Referring contact name should not be blank
           select 'Referral Pharmacy Contact Name should not be blank' as ExceptionReason
                 , a.AspnRxID
                 , ap.PrescriptionID
              from [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX a  
              left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX_PRESCRIPTION ap on ap.AspnRxID = a.AspnRxID
              where a.ProgramID in (31)
              and (@Startdate is null or (a.CreatedOn between @Startdate and getdate()))
              and (a.ReferringPharmacyContact is null or rtrim(ltrim(a.ReferringPharmacyContact)) = '')


            union
            -- 2.   Received/Referral Date should not be blank
            select 'Received/Referral date should not be blank' as ExceptionReason
                  , a.AspnRxID
                  , ap.PrescriptionID
            from [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX a 
            left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX_PRESCRIPTION ap on ap.AspnRxID = a.AspnRxID
            where a.ProgramID in (31)
            and (@Startdate is null or (a.CreatedOn between @Startdate and getdate()))
            and a.ReceivedOn is null


     ) /* end of CTE */


           select distinct
                  pe.ExceptionReason
                , pe.AspnRxID 
                , a.ProgramID
                , prg.ProgramName
                , coalesce(cp.ReferralType,a.ReferralType) ReferralType
                , a.RxType
                , a.ProgramStatus
                , a.ProgramSubstatus
                , a.ReceivedOn as ReceivedOnDate
                , a.PrescriptionDate
                , ap.FillDate
                , ap.ShipDate   
                , cp.Quantity as PrescriptionQuantity
                , ap.FillQty
                , ap.Indicator
                , a.CreatedOn as CreateDate
                , a.ModifiedOn as ModifyDate
                , a.AssignedOn as AssignDate
                , a.AcceptedOn as AcceptDate
                , a.CompletedOn as CompleteDate
                , a.CancelledOn as CancelDate
                , a.FillingPharmacyContact
                , a.ReferringPharmacyContact
                , m.MemberName as FillingPharmacyName
                , m2.MemberName as ReferringPharmacyName
                , cp.PrescriptionID
                , cp.DrugName
                , cp.Copay as PrescriptionCopay
                , a.ReferralCode
                , (select [TypeCode] from [ArmadaRX].[common].[INSURANCETYPE] where [InsuranceTypeID] = cp.InsuranceType) as InsuranceType
                , cp.InsuranceName
                , pd.NPI
                , cp.Binnumber

        from ProgramExceptions pe
          inner join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX a on a.AspnRxID = pe.AspnRxID
          left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX_PRESCRIPTION ap on ap.AspnRxID = pe.AspnRxID and (pe.PrescriptionID is null or ap.PrescriptionID = pe.PrescriptionID)  
          left outer join [ArmadaRX].common.PRESCRIPTION cp on cp.PrescriptionID = ap.PrescriptionID and (pe.PrescriptionID is null or cp.PrescriptionID = pe.PrescriptionID)
          left outer join ArmadaRX.aspn.PRESCRIPTIONDOCTOR pd on pd.PrescriptionID = cp.PrescriptionID
          left outer join [ArmadaRX].common.Patient p on p.patientID = a.PatientID
          left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.Program prg on prg.ProgramID = a.ProgramID
          left outer join ArmadaApproveRx.dbo.vMember m on m.MemberID = a.FillingPharmacyID
          left outer join ArmadaApproveRx.dbo.vMember m2 on m2.MemberID = a.ReferringPharmacyID

         where a.ProgramID in (31)
        order by pe.AspnRxID



end
```

Comment: check for date related columns

Comment: What is the issue with date? Can you explain in details?

Comment: What is the amount of rows in the tables?
Do you have appropriate indexes created for the tables?

CTEs can sometimes be slower than using Temp Tables if there is a vast amount of data

Comment: How can i implement temp table then on my query? Any example?

Comment: I don't like the sub-select for the insurance type. Can't you make it a regular join?

Comment: `Is there any better short way to write this same query?` we don't have this task with all the requirements and data model description in our task trackers. So, rewriting it with any other list of joins and/or predicates giving the equal output  would definitely be tricky for any of us. Do you have **actual execution plan**? Do you need all those distincts and cross-database joins?

Comment: Why is the query checking `@Startdate is null` when `@Startdate` is never null?

Comment: Can the date be in the future? If not, there is no point to test it against the current date (`getdate()`). Just test `a.CreatedOn >= @Startdate`.

Comment: What is chemotherapy and why you scared? @MitchWheat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, using CTEs for large datasets degrades the performance of the query. In switching CTEs to Temp tables, I have found large performance improvements as this does give me the ability to create indexes as needed. The code below is an example of transforming the OPs example query with a CTE to use a temp table.

```
USE [Analytics]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER procedure [vision].[SancusoReferralExceptionsReport]
as
begin
 Declare @programid varchar(30) ;
 DECLARE @Startdate DATETIME = '1900-01-01'
 set @programid = '31';

SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable
FROM (
    -- 1. Referring contact name should not be blank
   select 'Referral Pharmacy Contact Name should not be blank' as ExceptionReason
         , a.AspnRxID
         , ap.PrescriptionID
      from [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX a  
      left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX_PRESCRIPTION ap on ap.AspnRxID = a.AspnRxID
      where a.ProgramID in (31)
      and (@Startdate is null or (a.CreatedOn between @Startdate and getdate()))
      and (a.ReferringPharmacyContact is null or rtrim(ltrim(a.ReferringPharmacyContact)) = '')


    union
    -- 2.   Received/Referral Date should not be blank
    select 'Received/Referral date should not be blank' as ExceptionReason
          , a.AspnRxID
          , ap.PrescriptionID
    from [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX a 
    left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX_PRESCRIPTION ap on ap.AspnRxID = a.AspnRxID
    where a.ProgramID in (31)
    and (@Startdate is null or (a.CreatedOn between @Startdate and getdate()))
    and a.ReceivedOn is null
 ) AS T
select distinct
      pe.ExceptionReason
    , pe.AspnRxID 
    , a.ProgramID
    , prg.ProgramName
    , coalesce(cp.ReferralType,a.ReferralType) ReferralType
    , a.RxType
    , a.ProgramStatus
    , a.ProgramSubstatus
    , a.ReceivedOn as ReceivedOnDate
    , a.PrescriptionDate
    , ap.FillDate
    , ap.ShipDate   
    , cp.Quantity as PrescriptionQuantity
    , ap.FillQty
    , ap.Indicator
    , a.CreatedOn as CreateDate
    , a.ModifiedOn as ModifyDate
    , a.AssignedOn as AssignDate
    , a.AcceptedOn as AcceptDate
    , a.CompletedOn as CompleteDate
    , a.CancelledOn as CancelDate
    , a.FillingPharmacyContact
    , a.ReferringPharmacyContact
    , m.MemberName as FillingPharmacyName
    , m2.MemberName as ReferringPharmacyName
    , cp.PrescriptionID
    , cp.DrugName
    , cp.Copay as PrescriptionCopay
    , a.ReferralCode
    , (select [TypeCode] from [ArmadaRX].[common].[INSURANCETYPE] where [InsuranceTypeID] = cp.InsuranceType) as InsuranceType
    , cp.InsuranceName
    , pd.NPI
    , cp.Binnumber
from #TempTable pe
  inner join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX a on a.AspnRxID = pe.AspnRxID
  left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.ASPNRX_PRESCRIPTION ap on ap.AspnRxID = pe.AspnRxID and (pe.PrescriptionID is null or ap.PrescriptionID = pe.PrescriptionID)  
  left outer join [ArmadaRX].common.PRESCRIPTION cp on cp.PrescriptionID = ap.PrescriptionID and (pe.PrescriptionID is null or cp.PrescriptionID = pe.PrescriptionID)
  left outer join ArmadaRX.aspn.PRESCRIPTIONDOCTOR pd on pd.PrescriptionID = cp.PrescriptionID
  left outer join [ArmadaRX].common.Patient p on p.patientID = a.PatientID
  left outer join [ArmadaRX].aspn.Program prg on prg.ProgramID = a.ProgramID
  left outer join ArmadaApproveRx.dbo.vMember m on m.MemberID = a.FillingPharmacyID
  left outer join ArmadaApproveRx.dbo.vMember m2 on m2.MemberID = a.ReferringPharmacyID

where a.ProgramID in (31)
order by pe.AspnRxID

DROP TABLE #TempTable

end
```

Comment: yea this will be selected! great job by the way but if you add some explaination it helps  more

Comment: In my experience, using CTEs for large datasets degrades the performance of the query.  In switching CTEs to Temp tables, I have found large performance improvements as this does give me the ability to create indexes as needed.

The code above is an example of transforming the OPs example query with a  CTE to use a temp table.